# Change color of an item in beamer when moving to next time

Tags: beamer

I have three items in a beamer slide. They appear one after the other when I press next.
My problem is I want the first two items to change color when the third item appears. Please explain how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to write everything twice, you can simply use `\only<>{}` to change the colour

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item \only<3>{\color{red}}1
            \item \only<3>{\color{red}}2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

*To address the command about dvipsnames*

Since `beamer` internally already loads the `xcolor` package you can pass the `dvipsnames` like this:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item \only<3>{\color{Peach}}1
            \item \only<3>{\color{Peach}}2
            \item 3
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you please explain how to chose some other color than red? may be RGB or a list of accepted colors? I used \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} and color Peach, but got errors ): Error: LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor. Error: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Peach'

Comment: @MLT: see edit about xcolor option

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a more elegant solution but this one works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1,2>{
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item 1
\item 2
\item 
\end{itemize}
}

\only<3->{
\begin{itemize}
\uncover<3->{\item \textcolor{red}{1}}
\uncover<3->{\item \textcolor{blue}{2}}
\uncover<3->{\item 3}
\end{itemize}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]